# Off canvas menu animation

Tags: html, css, animation, canvas, zurb-foundation-5

I am currently working with Foundation 5 Off-canvas menus [Foundation off canvas menu](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html#idOfLeftMenu). Currently the off canvas menu opens from left to right.

My question is how is it possible to change the position of how the off canvas menu loads, default is left to right fadeIn convert to eg : top to bottom fadeIn. How can this be achieved? I have used `animate.css` and unsuccessful  in resulting the same. I have searched thourghly for solution but not have found any.

Im working on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanaka/e4h7f0pv/4/)

Comment: If you use the app foundation you can [try it](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/off-canvas)

Comment: can you be a bit clear on that?

Comment: There are 2 solutions push by zurb : [Classic](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [App](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/)

Comment: I dont want to use apps. Even classic uses the same push method. I need to overcome the default fadeIn position.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the **open event** to custom the animation

```
$(document).on('open.fndtn.offcanvas', '[data-offcanvas]', function () {
  var off_canvas_wrap = $(this);
});
```

because **Foundation 5 supports only right or left translation**

Comment: could you provide a fiddle for the solution?